# WKwbview navigationresponse how to get requested URL

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

In my wkwebview I have a link to some file like pages, numbers etc.  I see the wknavigationresponse decidepolicy to make a decision to download or show the content. However the wknavigation response object does not seem to contain the requested URL but apple modified url.  for example I request

https://www.sarvepalli.net/ax/Subscriptions%20Data.numbers

It gets translated to in wknavigationresponse.response.url like below:

x-apple-ql-id://4A35794C-554C-4732-9159-BFCB7A688F1D/x-apple-ql-magic/Subscriptions%20Data.numbers

I tired using the wknavigationaction to set a global variable called current_url but that does not seem to work as these methods are being either asynchronously called or called in reverse order than I had imagined (1) Wknavigationaction then (2) decidepolicyfor: WknavigationResponse

I am stuck any help in finding a way to collect the current URL being requested when a user clicks on a link in webview, it will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Vijay

```
/* This should get replaced by the navgationaction */
var current_url=   URL(string: "https://example.com/download/a.docx")!  

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
                 createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration,
                 for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
                 windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
        // if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil, let url = navigationAction.request.url {
        if navigationAction.request.url != nil, let url = navigationAction.request.url {
            //if url.description.lowercased().range(of: "http://") != nil ||
            self.current_url = url
           let url_request:URLRequest =  URLRequest(url: navigationAction.request.url!)
                    webView.load(url_request)
}

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
                 decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse,
                 decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
        let mimetype = navigationResponse.response.mimeType!
        let thisurl = navigationResponse.response.url?.absoluteString
        print("Current Url being requested is ",current_url.absoluteString)

        print("Current Url being considered ", navigationResponse.response.url?.absoluteString ?? "unknown");
         decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

I get strange response like

Current Url being requested is printed as "https://example.com/download/a.docx"
(This should be acctually be the  URL being clicked which is 
https://www.sarvepalli.net/ax/Subscriptions%20Data.numbers
)

Current Url being considered 
x-apple-ql-id://4A35794C-554C-4732-9159-BFCB7A688F1D/x-apple-ql-magic/Subscriptions%20Data.numbers
(This is an unusable internal URL specified by apple which is perhaps  being cached somewhere in the device)

Comment: I don't really get what you want to achieve, but I get a normal URL in `navigationResponse.response.url`. Actually I requested ""https://www.sarvepalli.net/ax/Subscriptions%20Data.numbers"" and retrieved `Optional(https://www.sarvepalli.net/ax/Subscriptions%20Data.numbers)` which seems to be what you need, right? So, I have the correct URL.

Comment: BTW, you don't need both conditions in the if statement in `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView?`. It's much cleaner if you simply use `if let url = navigationAction.request.url { ... }` then you can also use `url` inside of that if when you create the URLRequest without having to force-unwrap the `navigationAction.request.url!`.

Comment: Sorry If what I asked was not clear. I want to use the navigationresponse to decide what to do with different mime/type content.  But in order to save it with a async urlsession - I need the full URL which provided mimetype that cannot be rendered by the wkwebview!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue.  Looks like if I force a navigationpolicy lookup then this wkwebview delegate gets called every time and everything works fine like I expcted.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
             decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
             decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

    // if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil, let url = navigationAction.request.url {
    if navigationAction.request.url != nil, let url = navigationAction.request.url {
    self.curl = url
    decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
 }
```

Now self.curl the global variable gets updated with every URL call.

Thanks!
Vijay